# Variadic template constructor to fill internal vector of std::variant

Tags: c++, metaprogramming, variadic-templates

I got the following class

```
class A {
  std::string name;
  std::vector<std::variant<int,float>> data; 
};
```

my goal is to have a constructor to fill this class with variable number of argument. Examples

```
A("hello", 1, 2.0, 1)
A("hello", 1, 2.0, 1.2)
....
```

I tried something like

```
 template <typename... ARGS>
A(std::string n, ARGS... arguments) : name(n), data({arguments...}) {}
```

But the compiler complains that
non-constant-expression cannot be narrowed from type 'float' to 'std::vector::size_type'  in initializer list.

Comment: Did you consider passing floats instead of doubles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You trying to call the constructor of data a bunch of times in the initializer list. Remember that variadic templates are unfolded at *compile time*. You will likely need to handle this outside the initializer list. Something like:

```
template <typename... ARGS>
A(std::string n, ARGS... arguments) : name(n) {
    data.reserve(sizeof...(T));
    (data.emplace_back(arguments), ...);
}
```

Assuming you have fold expressions (AKA `c++17`). [Here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/24358328b10b026a) is a live example. As a further note, your variant should be a double, or you should specify your input with `2.0f` to avoid a narrowing conversion.

Comment: This is a strange way to do it.  I mean it works.  Might want to add a reserve.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont From a brief look, i cannot figure out how to make an std::initializer_list from a variadic template argument list. Do you know how?

Comment: Cast the elements?  Or name the list type explicitly.  Tge squggley braces are making an initializer list here already.  Just getting errors.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Yeah i tried generating the varients explicitly, i can get rid of the errors, but the result is just an initializer list with one element in it. I guess because we are utilizing the comma operator instead of making a real initializer list.

Comment: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/158bcd1547a778ca

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Very cool, is that aggregate initialization? How is that not just calling the vector constructor?

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont Also you should add that as an answer, it is better then mine.

Comment: Go ahead and update yours.  Easier than posting an answer on my phone.  I am lazy.